# What to do with disabled Software Sources after Ubuntu Upgrade

Tags: updates, 22.04, ubuntu-mate, software-sources

I upgraded from Ubuntu-MATE 20.04 to 22.04.

##### **What am I supposed to do with all these now-disabled sources?**

(admittedly some were probably disabled before)

- For some application-specifc ones „that I know“ like ffmpeg4 or digikam I would assume: simply re-enable?
- What about those "important [yet non-descript] security updates". Distribution says focal-security (which probably means version 20, Focal Fossa). → Delete?
- similar: impish main (Impish is release 21.x). → also Delete?
- What about "Recommended Updates"? That would usually be a different tab, “Updates”, right next to it? (And does `(Source Code)` imply it *only* or it *also* has source code? I am *not* into Ubuntu software development...)
- first 2 entries: Installation medium and -whatever- („non free drivers“) → Delete?

[image]

Comment: Anything *official* related to *focal* can be ignored as it no longer applies to your now *jammy* box, however for PPAs you'll need to check if the PPA provides support for *jammy*, you still trust it etc, then you can re-enable them if required. You mention however a *focal* (20.04) upgrade to *jammy* (20.04) but I also note *impish* (21.10) so you need to evaluate your system more closely as mixing sources is a recipe for *dep hell* type issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Evaluate each item on the list to see if that source is still needed and still available.**

This is the admin burden that you accept when you use non-Ubuntu sources. Check each source for:

- "`Installation media for...`": Delete, unless you plan to leave that installer plugged in and available.
- If you don't use that software anymore: Disable or delete the source.
- If the Ubuntu repositories now include the specific newer version you wanted: Disable the PPA or third-party repository.
- If PPA or third-party source has no corresponding package for your Ubuntu release yet: Disable the PPA or third-party repo until their packages become available.
- All `(Source Code)` sources can be safely deleted. If you don't know what the term "*source packages*" means, then you will never use those sources. If you DO know what the term means, then you already have the skill to reconstruct the URL for the source you want.
- Delete sources specific to an older (superseded) release of Ubuntu. You won't use those again. Ubuntu's release-upgrade script usually does this automatically, so this specific kind of detritus suggests haywiring or mucking with your sources that left a mess behind.
- NEVER disable or delete main, -updates, or -security for the current release of Ubuntu. You need those. Go ahead and delete main, -updates, and -security for **past** releases. You can disable other pockets of the **current** Ubuntu repositories like universe, multiverse, and partner...though if you enabled them for a reason, that reason might still be valid.